# How to plot histogram in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of items (duplicate items are there).

Total_Item={12,13,13,16,....10}

When I execute

```
 import collections
  ..
  ..

  print collections.Counter(Total_Item)
```

I got following output

```
Counter({13: 17, 12: 12, 14: 9, 15: 5, 11: 2, 17: 2, 10: 1, 16: 1})
```

I want to plot a histogram to show the distribution of different items in this list.

I have plotted using google sheet, but it is time consuming.

[image]

How to plot the histogram in python?

As per suggestion in comment and this link [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691123/ploting-matplotlib-histogram-in-python),
I am able to print the histogram.

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import collections
  ..
  ..

  print collections.Counter(Total_Item)
  plt.figure()
  plt.hist(Total_Item)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: What about matplotlib? https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: You might also be interested in Plotly: https://plot.ly/python/histograms/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example from
https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-histogram/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [21,22,23,4,5,6,77,8,9,10,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,18,49,50,100]
num_bins = 5
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21268820)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited the answer to include an example.

Comment: @dustinos3 If I want to create as many bins as many distinct values are there in x, then how to set num_bins ?